# Using a url variable, is there a way to display a draft post when not logged in

Tags: draft

Is there a method of displaying a post that is a draft when not logged in?

For example I have created a mailer template for my news...

```
<?php
if ( isset($_GET["mailer"]) )
get_template_part( 'mailers/template', 'news' );
else {
get_header(); ?>

    <!-- WEB TEMPLATE -->

<?php get_footer();
} ?>
```

This is on my `single-news.php` template.

As you can see my news mailer template is pulled in when I use this variable... `?mailer`

```
http://www.example.com/my-news-reports/?mailer
```

But I would like to be able to still use the mailer template even when in draft mode.

Is this possible with adding a variable like this.. `?mailer&draft=true`

I understand the 404 template is retrieved, and this may cause issues. Just wondering if there was a method I could adopt to get round this draft issue.

Thanks

Comment: Please take a look at the code [of this plugin](https://github.com/ocean90/public-post-preview/blob/master/public-post-preview.php) and improve your question with what you've tried (instead of what task you're trying to solve). Thanks.

Comment: No thank you, this plugin is absolute perfect. Great thanks!